# Og's bed made of iron

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, sleep, size, parshat-devarim, og

[Devarim 3:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=38) desribes Og's bed as being made from iron. What does the the Torah add by describing Og's bed as being made from iron? 
The Ramban comments that it demonstrates how tall he was, that wood would not have been strong enough. But surely a bed could be made of wood with the appropriate construction to carry any amount of weight. Also, being tall does necessarily equate to being heavy.

Comment: See [Gershon Gold's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18018/5) and consider revising your question. Are you asking for an explanation of the verse or an explanation of Ramban's interpretation of the verse?

Comment: +1. Re "being tall does necessarily equate to being heavy", well, it kinda does.

Comment: What the Ramban actually says is that it demonstrates his height **and size**, i.e. he was tall and heavy.

Answer (score 3):

The [Rashbam](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=39) explains that due to his strength he broke the wooden beds when he was younger and therefore they made a metal bed for him.

Comment: So is the Rashbam arguing with the Ramban? Or does this come to explain the Ramban? If the latter, how so?

Comment: It sounds to me like they are very similar, although the Rashbam is adding in that he actually broke the wood beds, and the Ramban just says that it would not be strong enough.

Comment: The Rashbam explains that it is referring to when he was a baby (translating "Arisaso" as "his crib"). His uncontrolled strength broke the wooden crib, so they made him a metal one. When he as older, and in control of himself, he no longer needed a metal bed.

Comment: I understood that Og was so large that he used a phone pole to brush his teeth and telegraph wire to floss! Most kids play with building blocks; Og played with just the buildings :-)

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Zvi Ron [opines](https://jbq.jewishbible.org/assets/Uploads/401/jbq_401_og.pdf) that iron was considered a precious metal in those times and thus Og's bed may have been a decorative treasure item. 
[This is now my own conjecture] Therefore the Torah may be describing the magnitude of the spoils